# git ignore all folder except a few with a common prefix

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore all files and folders except five folders that begin with a certain prefix. For example

1. Folder one
2. Folder two
3. prefix_folder_one
4. prefix_folder_two

I want to ignore everything except folders 3 and 4 and their content

I tried this but it didn't work

```
*
!.gitignore
!/prefix_*
```

I also tried writing the full names of folder 3 and 4 but it didn't work either. `git status` tells me that there are no files to commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will ignore all root files and root sub-directories, excluding the .gitignore file and the directories with the prefix `prefix_`

```
/*
/*/
!.gitignore
!/prefix_*
```

Git should now track the files in the directories with `prefix_` and ignore the rest.